# How to add ui tree massaction in sales order grid magento2?

Tags: magento2

How to add UI tree Massaction in sales order grid magento2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Is it getting an action to the list of actions, how to handle a request from the dropdown, both? It would also be helpful if you gave a little bit more context as to what you're trying to achieve, and what you've already tried or researched that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-treemassactions.html

Add below snippet at **view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml**

Output: https://prnt.sc/1rbil23

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <action name="info_delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">info_delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="vendormod/index/massdelete"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Blogs?</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete the selected blogs?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="status2">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">status2</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Change Status 2</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">sub_action1</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">#1 Inactive</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="vendormod/index/massstatus">
                        <param name="status">1</param>
                    </item>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Blogs?</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete the selected blogs?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">sub_action2</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">#2 Pending approval</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="vendormod/index/massstatus">
                        <param name="status">2</param>
                    </item>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Blogs?</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete the selected blogs?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">sub_action3</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">#3 Active</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="vendormod/index/massstatus">
                        <param name="status">3</param>
                    </item>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Blogs?</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete the selected blogs?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
</listingToolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks @Amir Khan. That is the answer, I need. Thanks for the answer.